# Android 6: file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen

Tags: android, linux, tcp, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there any kind stackoverflow member who can check the value in the file

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen`

on an Android 6 device?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I get on an Android 6.0.1 (MMB29K) Nexus 6:

```
shell@shamu:/ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen                             
0
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it rooted is it just adb?

Comment: adb, root was not needed, sorry